# What type of plug do I need to switch on a VL-CSH07G LED?

Tags: identification, mains, plug

I ordered it from this [site][1] , and the model is VL-CSH07G. What type of power/plug/pin do I need to power the LED on ? Link to the thing I am supposed to order or its name is optimum solution here

[image]

Comment: https://octopart.com/search?q=SMR-02V-B&currency=USD&specs=0

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, You need a dedicated led driver with constant current. You get the current in milliamps mA from the line "Power Consumption"  and you get the voltage in V from the line "Operating Voltage". The led driver you get will need to be able to provide 700mA at 3.2V and no more. You could limit that down to 650 or 600 mA if you want a long life to the led.

The connector type is listed by part number on the line "Connector". You could cut it off and replace it with a different connector if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the specs listed on that website that you need a low voltage constant current supply - that LED needs 700 mA at 3.2 volts (as with any other LED, you must control the current, and let the LED determine the voltage - you can't run it from a fixed 3.2 volt supply.)

Comment: what is it that I am supposed to buy to control it ?